# Why do I get NullPointerException ? (Basic GPS logic)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, gps

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;


public class DirectionGraphe {

    public ArrayList<GraphVector> shortest;
    public ArrayList<GraphVector> current_path;
    private ArrayList <GraphVector> fastest;
    private Integer weight_sum;
    private Integer current_gain;

    public DirectionGraphe(){
    }

    private ArrayList <GraphVector> graph = new ArrayList<GraphVector>();

    public ArrayList <GraphVector> getRoutes(GraphVector toncho){
        ArrayList<GraphVector> list = new ArrayList <GraphVector> ();

        for(GraphVector eachVector : graph){
            if(toncho.isRoute(eachVector)){
                list.add(eachVector);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public void addVector(GraphVector vector) throws Exception{
        if(isConnected(vector) || graph.isEmpty()){
            graph.add(vector);  
        }
        else throw(new Exception (" Vector is not connected ! "));
    }

    public boolean isConnected(GraphVector vector){     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        for(GraphVector v : graph){
            if(vector.isConnected(v)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public ArrayList<GraphVector> findShortestRoute(DecCoord start, DecCoord end){
        for(GraphVector v : graph){
            if(v.beginning.equals(start)){
                current_path.add(v);
                if(v.end.equals(end)){          //If we are to be in that scope it means this we have found a vector from A to B and within that scope here we are checking
                    if( shortest == null || shortest.isEmpty() || current_path.size() < shortest.size() ){ // to see if this VECTOR is shorter compared to the last vector
                        shortest = current_path;        
                        ArrayList <GraphVector> current_path2 = new ArrayList <GraphVector> ();///////////////////
                        current_path2.addAll(shortest);       /////////////                             // hack 
                        current_path.clear();     
                        shortest = current_path2; //////////
                    }
                } else {
                    for(GraphVector p : this.getRoutes(v)){         // 


                        System.out.println("shortest else " + shortest);
                        System.out.println("current path else " + current_path);


                        findShortestRoute(p.beginning,end);
                    }
                }
                current_path.remove(current_path.lastIndexOf(current_path));
            }
        }
        return shortest;
    }

    public ArrayList<GraphVector> findFastestRoute (DecCoord start, DecCoord end){
        for(GraphVector d : graph){
            if(d.beginning.equals(start) && current_path != null){
                current_path.add(d);
                if(d.end.equals(end)){
                    if(fastest == null || fastest.isEmpty() || gain(current_path) < gain(fastest)){
                        current_path = fastest;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    for(GraphVector z : this.getRoutes(d)){
                        findFastestRoute(z.beginning,end);
                    }
                }
                current_path.remove(current_path.lastIndexOf(current_path));
            }
        }


        return current_path;    
    }

    public Integer gain (ArrayList<GraphVector> current_path){ 
        for(GraphVector e : current_path){
            weight_sum =+ e.speed;
        }
        Integer size = current_path.size();
        current_gain = size/weight_sum; 
        System.out.println(current_gain);
        return current_gain;    
    }
}



import java.math.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class GPS_Fail {




    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int [][] coordinates = { 
                {45,60,90,43,80},
                {90,43,87,123,50},
                {87,123,111,133,120},
                {90,43,40,56,60},
                {40,56,111,133,90},
                {90,43,145,543,70},
                {145,543,344,54,20},
                {344,54,432,54,50},
                {432,54,111,133,70}};
        DirectionGraphe graphe = new DirectionGraphe();
        for(int i = 0; i< coordinates.length; i++ ){
            graphe.addVector(new GraphVector(new BigDecimal(coordinates[i][0]), new BigDecimal(coordinates[i][1]),new BigDecimal(coordinates[i][2]), new BigDecimal(coordinates[i][3]),(coordinates[i][4])));



        }
        DecCoord Lili = new DecCoord(new BigDecimal(45),new BigDecimal(60));
        DecCoord pich = new DecCoord(new BigDecimal(111),new BigDecimal(133)) ;
        graphe.findShortestRoute(Lili, pich);
        //graphe.findFastestRoute(Lili, pich);
    }
}
```

Hello everybody !
I have been assigned with the task to develop a basic GPS logic. These are the main and one of the additional classes I have created so far. The problem that I encounter is a NullPointerException after a day of debugging I couldn't find out why. The exception is appearing :

- in the main class at line 29(calling my method)
- in the subclass at 49 (current_path.add(v);)

My "guide" said me that it should work properly and I need to find the logical mistake within, but I couldn't do that until now.

I hope this info is enough and if not please ask whatever you need in order to understand the code above.

Comment: can you please post full stack trace?

Comment: your instance variables are all null

Comment: Please add a ***clear*** marking to the lines where the issue occurs, I don't want to count lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize `current_path`, so it is still `null` when you call `add(v)` on it. That is what is throwing the `NullPointerException`. You have to create a new `ArrayList` and assign it to `current_path` before you can use it. You can create it in the constructor.

```
public DirectionGraphe(){
    current_path = new ArrayList<GraphVector>();
}
```

Also, I would check your other instance variables and make sure they get initialized correctly. (such as `weight_sum`. It looks like you add a number to it before giving it a value)